# What's the adverb for Half-Assed?

Tags: word-request, adverbs

What's the adverb for the word *half-assed*?

I thought it was

> Half-assedly

but it seems like it might not be a real word...

Comment: That would make sense when comparing to *halfhearted* / *halfheartedly*, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: The  adverb of half-assed is half-assed. The adverb is itself half-assed. *They did it half-assed*.

Comment: +1 @TRomano See [**link**](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=half-assed) (but I've heard it also with the standard _-ly_ too, and there is [this.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=half%20assedly))

Comment: Wouldn't expect P.E. Dant to be citing Urban Dictionary :)

Answer (score 1):

As a native American English speaker I quite frequently say Half-assedly (Pronounced ass-ed-lee).  While I'm not sure if it's in every dictionary it is certainly well understood.